# bash conditional doesn't work inside while

Tags: bash

Inside while I get 1 printed in infinite loop, so why is not this comparison functioning correctly?

```
while [[ "$(mysql -u root -e "select 1")" != 1 ]]; do
    mysql -u root -e "select 1"
    sleep 1
  done
```

Output

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
0000004
0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
0000004
0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
0000004
0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
0000004
0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
0000004
0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
0000004
0000000   1  \n   1  \n
           0a31    0a31
```

Comment: What does `mysql -u root -e "select 1"` output, exactly? When I do that I get an ASCII-formatted table back.

Comment: @Kusalananda I get 1 outputted.

Comment: No spaces before or after?

Comment: @Kusalananda maybe it contains newline? I updated the post with output

Comment: `while [[ " 1" != 1 ]]; do ... done` is an infinite loop. As is using `"1 "`.

Comment: @Kusalananda how do I cast it to integer?

Comment: What is  the output of `mysql -u root -e "select 1" | od -cx` ?

Comment: @WalterA I updated OP, its newline yes.

Comment: It seems you get two lines of output, can you `select distinct 1` ?

Comment: @WalterA output is same

Comment: I do not know what will happen when you add `|uniq` behind the sql, perhaps add some debug info in the loop: `output="$(mysql -u root -e "select 1")"; echo "output=[${output}]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL select statement `select 1` will return two things:

1. A column name.
2. A value.

The column name is `1`, and the value is also `1`.

To avoid getting the column name in the output use the `--skip-column-names` (or `-N`) option to `mysql`.

You might also want to use `--batch` (`-B`) as this disables the generation of an ASCII-formatted table for those that hasn't this turned off by default:

```
$ mysql (options) -e 'select 1'
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

$ mysql -N (options) -e 'select 1'
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

$ mysql -B -N (options) -e 'select 1'
1
```